# TikZ rectangle split with changing alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I try to draw tikz nodes with `rectangle split`. I want the first part to be centered and the second part aligned left. This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}
  \tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, draw=black, text width=3cm,
                   rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) [box] {
      First
      \nodepart{second}Second
    };
    \node (B) [below=of A, box] {
      \begin{center}First\end{center}
      \nodepart{second}Second
    };
    \node (C) [below=of B, box, align=center] {
      First
      \nodepart{second}\flushleft Second
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`A` has the correct size, but everything is left-aligned.

`B` has correct alignment, but the first part is larger than it needs to be.

`C` also has correct alignment, but the second part is largen than it needs to be.

[image]

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `nodepart`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
  \tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, draw=black, text width=3cm,
                   rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=center] (A) [box] {
      First
      \nodepart[align=left]{second}Second
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`text width` would seem to be the problem. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\tikzset{%
    box/.style={draw,minimum width=3cm,
                   rectangle split, 
                   rectangle split parts=2,
                   rectangle split part align={center,left}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) [box] {
      First
      \nodepart{second}Second
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```